# Binary Search Assembly 68HC11

Tags: assembly, binary-search, 68hc11

I have to make a binary search algorithm in Assembly (69HC11) with loops. This is what I have done:

```
    ORG $C400
;n1-n5 will have numbers
N1 RMB 2
N2 RMB 2
N3 RMB 2
N4 RMB 2
N5 RMB 2
IZQ RMB 2
DER RMB 2
;Here is where is going to be the answer
MID RMB 2
;The number im searching
T RMB 2
    ORG $C500
LDD #$400
STD IZQ
LDD #$408
STD DER
LOOP:   LDD IZQ
        ADDD DER
        LDX #2
        IDIV
        STX MID
        LDD MID
        CPD #T
        BLO LAZO1
        BHI LAZO2
        BEQ LAZO3
        LDD IZQ
        CPD DER
        BLS LOOP
LAZO1:
;izq = mid + 1
    INX
    STX IZQ
    BRA LOOP

LAZO2:
;der = mid - 1
    DEX
    STX DER
    BRA LOOP

LAZO3:
Fin:  BRA Fin
```

The problem is that the loop I want to calculate the mid position and then storage in D the value that is in that position. I tried to write something like $MID but is not posible.

Comment: Is that `IDIV` just dividing by two?  Use a right shift.

Comment: Several problems with your code.  BLO BHI BEQ in sequence takes care of all possibilities.  What follows is, therefore, unreachable code.  Also, you need to use index X to point to the data array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(First of all I have used this assembler: http://www.aspisys.com/asm11.htm
It may need some minor syntax adjustments to make it compatible to
another assembler.  For example, the @@ indicates local symbols within the
current PROC.)

It's better to work with simple indices (0..N-1) rather than actual
memory addresses which depending on the word size may make it more
difficult to calculate the mid point.

For greater simplicity you could use single byte head and tail
variables but then your maximum array would be limited to 256 entries.
I left it as word, giving a maximum of 64K entries.

I used a static array (residing in ROM) for initialization simplicity.
If you want the array to be in RAM, you need to first initialize it with
some data, and rather than using DW directives, you should instead use
RMB WORD_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE to allocate the memory area.

There is no need for using global variables at all.  You could write
the BinarySearch routine so that it can be used with different tables.  For
example, the target value could be passed in register D, the starting
address of the array in register X, and the number of array elements in
register Y.  Then, your work variables (mid_point, target, head, and tail)
could all be dynamically allocated on the stack upon entry to Search, and
de-allocated before exit, while load the result (mid_point) into register
X (for example).

All registers are destroyed inside BinarySearch.  Use PUSH on entry and PULL
on exit if you want them protected.

BinarySearch exits with Carry Clear if target is found, and the mid_point
variable updated with the related pointer.  Carry is Set if target is not
found, and mid_point is 'garbage'.

```
;*******************************************************************************
; Constants
;*******************************************************************************

STACKTOP            equ       $0DFF
Vreset              equ       $FFFE

VARS_ORG            equ       $0300
ARRAY_ORG           equ       $C400
CODE_ORG            equ       $C500

;*******************************************************************************
; Variables
;*******************************************************************************

                    #RAM
                    org       VARS_ORG

mid_point           rmb       2                   ; eventually holds the answer
target              rmb       2                   ; the number to search for

head                rmb       2                   ; head work pointer
tail                rmb       2                   ; tail work pointer

;*******************************************************************************
; Code
;*******************************************************************************

                    #ROM
                    org       ARRAY_ORG           ;wherever you want your array to be

array               dw        1000
WORD_SIZE           equ       *-array             ;bytes per entry in array
                    dw        2000
                    dw        3000
                    dw        4000
                    dw        5000
                    dw        6000
                    dw        7000
                    dw        8000
                    dw        9000
ARRAY_SIZE          equ       *-array/WORD_SIZE

;*******************************************************************************

                   ;org       CODE_ORG            ;wherever you want your code to be

BinarySearch        proc
                    clra                          ;D = 0
                    clrb
                    std       head                ;initialize head pointer to zero

                    ldd       #ARRAY_SIZE-1       ;initialize tail pointer to N-1
                    std       tail

Loop@@              ldd       head
                    addd      tail
                    rora                          ;LSRD will not work if previous
                    rorb                          ; ADDD produced a carry
                    std       mid_point           ;update mid_point
                    lsld                          ;multiply by WORD_SIZE (x2 -- a shift left will do)
                    addd      #array              ;offset into array
                    xgdx                          ;X = pointer

                    ldd       target              ;target number to search for
                    cpd       ,x                  ;compare against array value
                    beq       Found@@             ;if equal, we're done
                    bhi       Upper@@             ;if greater than, use upper half
;                   blo       Lower@@             ;if less than, use lower half

Lower@@             ldx       mid_point           ;tail = mid_point - 1
                    dex
                    stx       tail
                    bra       Cont@@

Upper@@             ldx       mid_point           ;head = mid_point + 1
                    inx
                    stx       head

Cont@@              ldx       head
                    cpx       tail
                    bls       Loop@@

NotFound@@          sec                           ;indicates 'not found'
                    bra       Done@@

Found@@             ldd       mid_point
                    lsld
                    addd      #array
                    std       mid_point
                    clc                           ;indicates 'found'
Done@@              rts

;*******************************************************************************

Start               proc
                    lds       #STACKTOP

                    ldd       #12345
                    std       target
                    bsr       BinarySearch

                    ldd       #5000
                    std       target
                    bsr       BinarySearch

                    ldd       #3000
                    std       target
                    bsr       BinarySearch

                    bra       *

;*******************************************************************************

                    #VECTORS
                    org       Vreset
                    dw        Start
```

Comment: Hey Tony, how are you?. I am new to the 68hc11 microcontroller and i've seen many threads and you know a lot about it. Could you please take a look at this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238168/68hc11-assembly-first-steps-sorting?noredirect=1#comment110073974_62238168 . You are the only one! :)