# Swapping positions (HC11)

Tags: assembly, 68hc11

I'm just playing with my **MC 68HC11**; in C i can perform a simple byte swap by doing something like this:

```
swapped = ((num>>24)&0xff) | // move byte 3 to byte 0
                    ((num<<8)&0xff0000) | // move byte 1 to byte 2
                    ((num>>8)&0xff00) | // move byte 2 to byte 1
                    ((num<<24)&0xff000000); // byte 0 to byte 3
```

But now i want to achieve something a little harder using assembly code:

I created an ARRAY and added some values (using little endian logic). I want to read that ARRAY and swap  all the values into big endian logic and store them inside "BIGENDIAN". 
I was thinking something like this:

```
RWM     EQU $0
ROM     EQU     $C000
RESET       EQU     $FFFE

        ORG     RWM
BIGENDIAN   RMB  16 

        ORG     ROM
Main:       


END     BRA END

ARRAY   DW  $0124,$FEEB,$0011,$0070,$ABEF,$074B,$8004,$8080

        ORG RESET
        DW  Main
```

I tried but it did not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DW` creates 16-bit words.
(Your C example is for 32-bit words.)

For 16-bit one possibility is this:

```
RAM                 equ       $0
ROM                 equ       $C000
Vreset              equ       $FFFE

                    org       RAM

BIGENDIAN           rmb       16

                    org       ROM

ARRAY               dw        $0124,$FEEB,$0011,$0070,$ABEF,$074B,$8004,$8080

Start               ldx       #ARRAY              ;X -> source
                    ldy       #BIGENDIAN          ;Y -> destination

Loop                ldd       ,x                  ;A = MSB, B = LSB (big endian view)
                    staa      1,y
                    stab      ,y

; one alternative for above two instructions
;                   pshb
;                   tab
;                   pula
;                   std       ,y

                    ldab      #2                  ;B = word size
                    abx                           ;X -> next word
                    aby                           ;Y -> next word

                    cpx       #ARRAY+::ARRAY
                    blo       Loop

Done                bra       *

                    org       Vreset
                    dw        Start
```

If you meant 32-bit words, so two 16-bit should be considered one word, I'll revise.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to me!. Tony, can check this different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313417/counting-number-hc11 ?