# Positive, negative and zero (assembly)

Tags: assembly, 68hc11

I'm programming an old MCU (68hc11), I'm trying to migrate from C language to assembly code using the 68hc11 instructions.

I want to write a program in assembly that counts the number of POSITIVE, NEGATIVE, and ZERO values that exist inside a given array. DO NOTE that all values inside ARRAY could be all positive or all negative or all zeros,do you get me? So I should define the size of the variables that will store the quantity properly.

NOTE: The end of the array is: ARRAY+QUANTITY-1

> Array: contains some random values
>
> QUANTITY: represent the highest number of elements that the ARRAY can
> hold

I wrote this program in C:

```
int A[15], pos, neg, nul, i;

[...]

pos = 0;
neg = 0;
nul = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (A[i] > 0) {
        pos++;
    }
    if (A[i] < 0) {
        neg++;
    }
    if (A[i] == 0) {
        nul++;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to translate that but in assembly (I GOT STUCK IN HERE, i'm not getting what i want)

```
RWM         EQU $0
ROM         EQU   $C000
VRESET      EQU   $FFFE

QUANTITY    EQU 800 ;MEANS THE MAXIMUM AMOUNT OF VALUES THAT THE ARRAY WILL CONTAIN

            ORG RWM

POSITIVE        RMB 2
NEGATIVE        RMB 2
ZEROS           RMB 2

            ORG ROM
START:
            CLRA
            CLRB
            CLR POSITIVE
            CLR ZEROS
            CLR NEGATIVE
            LDY #ARRAY
            
LOOP
            CPY #(ARRAY+QUANTITY-1)

            BHI END
            LDD 0,Y
            INY
            BLT NEGATIVE_NUMBER
            BEQ ZERO_NUMBER
            BGE POSITIVE_NUMBER
            
            
NEGATIVE_NUMBER     INC NEGATIVE
                        BRA LOOP
                        
POSITIVE_NUMBER     INC POSITIVE
                        BRA LOOP
                        
ZERO_NUMBER         INC ZEROS
                        BRA LOOP
                        

END         BRA END

ARRAY       DW    78,554,-44,-4,2547,0,-3,0,1,7,8,

        ORG VRESET
        DW  START
```

What's wrong with my code?

EDIT:

[image: ERROR]

```
RWM         EQU $0
ROM         EQU   $C000
VRESET      EQU   $FFFE

QUANTITY    EQU 800 ;MEANS THE MAXIMUM AMOUNT OF VALUES THAT THE ARRAY WILL CONTAIN

            ORG RWM

POSITIVE        RMB 2
NEGATIVE        RMB 2
ZEROS           RMB 2

            ORG ROM
START:
            CLRA
            CLRB
            CLR POSITIVE
            CLR ZEROS
            CLR NEGATIVE
            LDY #(ARRAY-2)
            
LOOP
             INY
         INY
             CPY #(ARRAY+2*QUANTITY-1)
         BHI END
         LDD 0,Y
         BLT NEGATIVE_NUMBER
                 BEQ ZERO_NUMBER
                 BGE POSITIVE_NUMBER
            
            
NEGATIVE_NUMBER     INC NEGATIVE
                        BRA LOOP
                        
POSITIVE_NUMBER     INC POSITIVE
                        BRA LOOP
                        
ZERO_NUMBER         INC ZEROS
                        BRA LOOP
                        

END         BRA END

ARRAY       DW    78,554,-44,-4,2547,0,-3,0,1,7,8,

        ORG VRESET
        DW  START
```

I got this output (not sure about it)

[image: inage]

Comment: What does "not getting what i want" mean?  The things that jump out as wrong are that you're incrementing your address by 1 each time through the loop - but the array elements are 2 bytes long; and you're looping over 800 addresses, even though only the first few of those have defined contents.

Comment: Hint: you can simplify the branching by computing one of the quantities from the other 2.  e.g. count negative and zero, and calculate after the loop `positive = quantity - neg - zero`

Comment: Hey @jasonharper ,thank you for replying. I mean, i'm running my code and it is not doing what i want; i'm kinda lost (not an expert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong with my code?

I only had a quick look at your program, so my answer may be wrong:

> ```
> LDD 0,Y
> ```

Obviously you are operating with 16 bit numbers. Otherwise you would use `LDA` or `LDB` instead of `LDD`.

> ```
> CPY #(ARRAY+QUANTITY-1)
> ```

This would be correct if `QUANTITY` is the size of the array in bytes (e.g. 30 in the case of `int A[15]`).

If `QUANTITY` is the number of elements and you are operating with 16-bit numbers, you have to multiply with two:

```
CPY #(ARRAY+2*QUANTITY-1)
```

> ```
> INY
> ```

Once again this would work for 8-bit elements. For 16-bit elements you have to add two to each element or to increment `Y` twice:

```
INY
INY
```

> ```
> INY
> BLT NEGATIVE_NUMBER
> ```

The `INY` instruction will modify the zero flag and therefore influence the `BLT`, `BGE` and `BEQ` instructions. You cannot use `INY` between `LDD` and the branch instructions.

> ```
> BLT ...
> BEQ ...
> BGE ...
> ```

Not really an error, but the `BGE` instruction will always branch. You may place the `POSITIVE_NUMBER` number code after the `BEQ` instruction and remove the `BGE` instruction.

**EDIT**

> I'm not understanding this part: `INY` followed by `Bxx`

I was thinking about three different ways to do this. The simplest one seems to be:

```
    LDY #(ARRAY-2)  ; Because we'll do INY twice right now
LOOP
    INY
    INY
    CPY #(ARRAY+2*QUANTITY-1)
    BHI END
    LDD 0,Y
    BLT NEGATIVE_NUMBER
    ...
```

Comment: Hey Martin, thank you for replying.I'm not understanding this part: INY
BLT NEGATIVE_NUMBER, not really sure how to solve that.

Comment: Martin, i feel a little dumb in this part: what would it be the big difference between *LDY #ARRAY* and *LDY #(ARRAY-2)*

Comment: Dude, i've updated my question; after running your code i got some syntax errors.

Comment: @Student_new Does `ARRAY+QUANTITY-1` work? If yes, the assembler might not support multiplication; try `ARRAY+QUANTITY+QUANTITY-1` instead of `ARRAY+2*QUANTITY-1`.

Comment: It is working now but not sure about what i'm getting (i've updated my question)

Comment: After `LDD` use `BPL` for positive, `BEQ` for zero, `BMI` for negative.  Although, once you have tested two of them, the third is implied and can fall-through to the respective `INC` without an explicit branch instruction.  @Student_new Some assemblers may complain about forward references.  So, define your array before (higher up the file) you refer to it.

Comment: Hey Tony, how is it goin'?. i modified my code according to your comment (https://imgur.com/a/QQzqk96). I'm getting this output, something does not make sense to me: https://imgur.com/a/86ID2uG

Comment: @Student_new I assume by that you mean the results don't match your array (the negative in particular).  Check the assembler listing for `CPY #(ARRAY+2*QUANTITY-1)` instruction.  Does it actually compare against the expected value?  Some assemblers (like my ASM11) process expressions left to right (i.e. no multiplication precedence), such that the expression evaluates to ((ARRAY+2)*QUANTITY)-1 making your code run over a completely different set of values than you expect.  Also, your counters should by byte sized for this example.

Comment: @Student_new It will be more helpful to show listing so that one can check the actual code generated (e.g., I can only guess what `QUANTITY` you have defined.  Is it 11 or something else?)